# Parsing a Stream of JSON Objects in an Android Recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I am trying to parse a URL that has a list of JSON objects attached to it, that looks like the following:

```json
    {
       "to":{
          "id":"X/4w7pz9L48=",
          "name":"Willie Hart"
       },
       "from":{
          "id":"YziKGGTsckQ=",
          "name":"Andy Stafford"
       },
       "timestamp":"1633376913009",
       "areFriends":true
    }{
       "to":{
          "id":"xRstXf+DJKw=",
          "name":"Clarence Hansen"
       },
       "from":{
          "id":"JUVS3wLLBPA=",
          "name":"Terry Russell"
       },
       "timestamp":"1633376913018",
       "areFriends":true
    }{
```

It is not in a valid JSON format, but I am trying to parse this into a recyclerview in my Android application, but am unable to parse just the JSONObjects I see in this file. Here is a sample of what I have to parse the data:

```java
    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String current = "";

            try
            {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL("https://codechallenge.secrethouse.party/?since=[timestamp_in_seconds]");
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                    InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                    int data = isw.read();

                    while(data != -1)
                    {
                        current += (char) data;
                        data = isw.read();
                    }

                    return current;
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(urlConnection != null)
                    {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            }
            return current;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                //parse the 'To" object
                JSONObject toNameObject = obj.getJSONObject("to");
                toNameList.add(toNameObject.getString("name"));

                //parse the 'From' object
                JSONObject fromNameObject = obj.getJSONObject("from");
                fromNameList.add(fromNameObject.getString("name"));

                //parse the 'Timestamp' object
                timeStampList.add(obj.getString("timestamp"));
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The error I get from running this is: `org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

My question is, with this link pointing to a whole bunch of JSONObjects, is it possible to parse just those objects? Or does the link need to point to a valid JSON file with correct structure?

Comment: If you have a say in how the Json data is structured (it sounds like you do) then why not just make it valid Json to make life much easier?

Comment: The client I'm doing this for gave me this as is, and want me to parse the information as is. In that case, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: you need some sort of delimiter to split on, typically in json like this its a line return but that does not appear to be the case here, I dont see any good way to parse it consistently. IMO you should go back to them and say to at least do the bare minimum and split the objects by a line return

Comment: according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)), getJSONObject Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject, or throws otherwise. Also remember you seem to have JSONArray with JSONObjects.